# Qual o nome das Tabs(Abas) que estão sendo usadas nos novos apps?

Tags: android

É uma tab que quando vc desliza do conteúdo da Tab para o lado vai para a nova tab. Na nova atualização do Youtube implementaram isso e eu queria saber o nome para implementar no meu app.
[Link da tab do youtube.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube&hl=pt-BR)

Imagem da atualização:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7):

Isso é chamado de `TabLayout`, depois que a  Google liberou o *Android 5.0* as `ActionBar` ficaram **deprecated** segue abaixo exemplo de como implementar retirado [daqui](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout).

**Tab Layout**, precisa adicionar o suporte `android.support.design.widget.TabLayout` e `android.support.v4.view.ViewPager`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:tabMode="scrollable" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

**Fragment**, você pode ter um ou mais dependendo da sua demanda

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center" />
```

**Fragment.java**, logica para seu fragment.

```
// In this case, the fragment displays simple text based on the page
 public class PageFragment extends Fragment {
public static final String ARG_PAGE = "ARG_PAGE";

private int mPage;

public static PageFragment newInstance(int page) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, page);
    PageFragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mPage = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_page, container, false);
    TextView textView = (TextView) view;
    textView.setText("Fragment #" + mPage);
    return view;
}
 }
```

**FragmentAdapter**, aqui será controlado sua `ViewPager`.

```
public class SampleFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
final int PAGE_COUNT = 3;
private String tabTitles[] = new String[] { "Tab1", "Tab2", "Tab3" };
private Context context;

public SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Context context) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return PAGE_COUNT;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return PageFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    // Generate title based on item position
    return tabTitles[position];
}
 }
```

**Configurando o slide das tabs**, aqui será feito em duas etapas :

1- no método `OnCreate` a `ViewPager` se conecta com o adapter.
2- Defina o `ViewPager` no `TabLayout` para atribuir o pager com as guias.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Get the ViewPager and set it's PagerAdapter so that it can display items
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new SampleFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), 
        MainActivity.this));

    // Give the TabLayout the ViewPager
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}

 }
```

**Saida:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 4):

No princípio do Material Design esse componente se chama [`Tabs`](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#), assim mesmo.

No caso do Youtube, ali tem um `ViewPager` com o componente de tabs, onde cada item do `ViewPager` tem uma tab representante.

Se você usa as bibliotecas de suporte (`support v4` e/ou a `appcompat v7`) você pode usar o `TabLayout` da [`design library`](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) do google, que tem vários componentes e classes com comportamentos específicos do Material Design.

Se tu usas o Android Studio, basta incluí-la como dependência:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

Lembrando que a versão 22.2.1 corrige diversos bugs da versão 22.2.0.

Usando o componente `TabLayout` é bem simples, o mais simples é:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabGravity="fill" />

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Configurando na sua `Activity` ou `Fragment`:

```
TabLayout tabLayout = ...;
PagerAdapter adapter = ...;
ViewPager viewPager = ...;

tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);
tabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(adapter);
```

Uma boa fonte para conhecer os demais componentes da `design library` é  http://android-developers.blogspot.com.br/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html