# Como se chama aquele efeito de "mudança de view" deslizando?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, front-end, touch

Vários apps (Facebook, Twitter, Instagram) fazem uso de um efeito "touch enabled" onde o usuário arrasta toda a tela e ele altera a view. Não confundir com o efeito "slide" do menu.

Eu gostaria de desenvolver um app com este efeito, mas não consigo encontrar nenhuma fonte sobre este assunto, pois nem sei o NOME deste componente ou efeito.

Só para ilustrar: no Whatsapp ele altera as opções CONVERSAS, STATUS e CHAMADAS

Comment: É esse aqui: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: O exemplo apresenta bem o efeito de mudança de view que eu desejo. Gostaria de saber agora se, tomando os exemplos que citei no texto acima, eu teria como controlar o efeito de mudança da view juntamente do indicador de seleção (normalmente representado por uma linha sublinhando a seleção)?

Comment: Sim, você pode sem nenhum problema.

Comment: Tentarei pesquisar em como fazê-lo.

Comment: Acho que essa resposta pode te ajudar: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76483/qual-o-nome-das-tabsabas-que-est%C3%A3o-sendo-usadas-nos-novos-apps/76495#76495. Você precisa implementar o ViewPager e o TabLayout.

Comment: Ótima implementação. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entendi que esse efeito responde a uma implementação que respeita o padrão de interface da Material Design.

Existem implementações Android / iOS.

https://developer.android.com/design/material/index.html

https://material.io/components/ios/

Answer (score 0):

No caso da plataforma iOS, pelo que você descreve, acho que é usado o `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`.
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiswipegesturerecognizer

Answer (score -1):

Eu acho que te queres referir a containers tipo Navigation container por exemplo. Nesses View controllers podes fazer slide que ele faz pop do view controller do topo da stack.